# How to test variable in python?

Tags: python, math, while-loop, try-catch, quadratic

I am new to python and I got everything I need in my script to run except I need variable "a" to not be accepted if it is "0"and if it is "0" tell the user to input a number other than 0. How do I do this?

```
1 #!/usr/bin python 3
2
3 import cmath
4 import math
5 import sys
6
7 print ("ax^2 + bx + c = 0")
8
9 while True:
10
11         try:
12                 a = float(input("Enter a: "))
13                 b = float(input("Enter b: "))
14                 c = float(input("Enter c: "))
15         except ValueError:
16                 print("Please enter a number!")
17         else:
18                 print (a,"x^2 + ",b,"x + ",c," = 0")
19                 x = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
20
21                 x1 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(x))/(2*a)
22                 x2 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(x))/(2*a)
23
24                 print ("x1= ",x1)
25                 print ("x2= ",x2)
26
27 exit(0)
```

~
~
~
~

Comment: You've got the except there already... you could just add `if not a: raise ValueError` in your `try`...

Comment: try -> except -> else is not a good pattern.

Comment: @Frank nothing wrong with it - I'd do away with the `else` but...

Comment: @JonClements yes, try-except is OK but the else should be removed.

Comment: @Frank: the `else` block isn't wrong, exactly, but it's not what the `else` clause of a `try...except` block should be used for, so I agree it's unnecessary clutter. And perhaps bob george thinks it _is_ necessary, so it's good that we're telling him that it's not.

Comment: @PM2Ring agree, it is not a wrong syntax, just an unnecessary line.

Comment: @FrankZhang: Yes. An unnecessary line, which leads to unnecessary indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `a` input section of your code to:

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
if a == 0.0:
    print('a must be non-zero!')
    continue
```

The `continue` statement says to immediately go to the top of the (innermost) loop.

Instead of the `continue` statement, you could `raise ValueError` (as Jon suggests) if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Use if:

```
if a != 0:
    do something
```

Comment: Yes but where in the script do I input this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just do:
    if a==0:
        print "Enter a valid number!"
        continue

... And repeat for each other variable. Use conditional statements. Also, if you use the float function instead of the int, it'll be "if a==0.0" or "if a!=0.0"

And you can create a def() function to handle number inputs to save typing such as:

```
def input_number():
    while True:
        try:
            n=float(input())
            if n!=0.0: return n
        except:
            print "Enter a valid number!"
```

Then just call it like:

```
a=input_number()
```

Comment: The `if a == 0.0` isn't required... `float(0) == int(0)`.

Comment: Haha, right... I use 2.7 so I am not familiar with their floating point numbers and inputs and literals. :)

Comment: @JonClements: `if a == 0.0` isn't required, but it's still stylistically nice to compare like with like. I'd probably just use `if not a`, but I'm trying to break that habit. :)

Comment: @Chris We don't want a general zero tester here, since it's only `a` that should be non-zero, `b==0` &/or `c==0` are valid in quadratics.

Comment: Haha, true... Then just remove the conditional "a==0" to after the input of the number!